# Is there a way to preprocess a single image using the same method as in tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, image-processing

I have trained a keras model and used `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory` to preprocess the images.

Now when I'm trying to test the model on a single image it's always predicting the same class with 99% accuracy so I think it's a preprocessing issue.

here's the code for the training preprocessing

```
val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  'dataset/PlantVillage',
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(256, 256),
  batch_size=64)
```

and here's the codeI have used to preprocess the images to test it

```
def preprocess_image(image_path):
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    image = image.resize((256, 256))  # Resize to match model's input size
    image_array = np.array(image)
    image_array = np.expand_dims(image_array, axis=0)  # Add batch dimension
    return image_array
```

I have compared their outputs and they looked the same, but the model keeps returning the same wrong prediction.

if the preprocessing is irrelevant to my issue, kindly tell me so I can look into other areas.